# How can I capture a specific ROI of raspberry pi camera?

Tags: camera, raspberry-pi, roi, raspistill

I want to capture a specific ROI (say 20x1800 region) of raspberry pi camera. First, I used the `raspistill --roi`. It gave me a zoomed image. The same happend with picamera `crop` method. So I decided to capture the whole image by raspicam and then using OpenCV to crop the image. It gave me a 20-27 frames per second. Isn't there any faster solution?

Comment: Please be more explicit about the **precise** command you used. Please also be a bit clearer about how long it actually takes and why that's too slow.

Comment: I didn't use a command for reading the whole image and then cropping it. I wrote a c++ program that includes raspicam to read the frames in 1920x1080 resolution and then uses OpenCV to crop them. The FPS was 20-28 on Raspberry Pi 3 B+.

Comment: I cannot understand. In your question, you said you used `raspistill` followed by `picamera` crop. Now you are saying in your comment you used OpenCV?

Comment: Sorry, I just edited the comment.

Comment: I said that the slowness is for reading the whole image and then cropping it. I didn't mention any speed concern for raspistill or crop method. The problem with these two solutions is the zoomed image

Comment: I am still having difficulty understanding - please show the **Minimum Complete Verifiable Example** of your code https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example You talk about `raspistill` implying you are capturing still images then you talk about frames per second implying you are capturing video. Which is it please? Please show the simplest possible code and say what you are actually trying to do.